# Cooking for Engineers

Tags: discussion

I know this is a cooking site, but the seed population is probably from Stack Overflow and its "trilogy" and is thus technically inclined.

If it's not already in the works, it seems a perfect match that the cooking Stack Exchange should have some kind of professional relationship with http://www.cookingforengineers.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I wouldn't dismiss outright any opportunities for cross-promotion, this really isn't the focus of the site. Any perception of this forum being "technical people who are cooks" is accidental, at best.

At the rate these sites grow, the majority-position held by technical users will diminish very quickly.

Comment: I follow this site. We might be able to get the guy who runs that site to mention us. Or does Stack Exchange advertise?

Comment: @mohlsen: If you can make a contact, great! That's *exactly* the type of help we need from you guys. We're not the "cooking experts" here. You are! And we will definitely be looking for ways to promote and advertise this site.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously contacted the guy behind cookingforengineers.com with the intention of doing something similar for the UK locale, but I didn't personally find him open to the ideas of working in collaboration with another site at that time.